# Why does my code have an "Apple Mach-O Linker Error?"

Tags: c++, xcode, error-handling, linker

I get this error when i build the program: `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error` `Linker Command failed with exit code 1`. Usually when I try to fix this error, its because the file with the main function is `#include`-ing a file more than once. However, I do not believe that that is the case this time. I am also notified by X Code that the `duplicate symbol _passed in:` `ranker.o` and `olympic.o`.

```
//competitor.h

#ifndef __Olympic_Lab__competitor__
#define __Olympic_Lab__competitor__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 class Competitor {
     char* name = nullptr;
     int laneAssignment;    
     float time;
 public:
    Competitor(char n[], int lane);
    ~Competitor();
    void setTime(float f);
    char* getName(){    return name;    }
    int getLane(){      return laneAssignment;    }
    float getTime(){    return time;    }
    void print(){   cout << name << endl;    }
 };
#endif 

//competitor.cpp

#include "competitor.h"
Competitor::Competitor(char n[], int lane){
    name = n;
    laneAssignment = lane;
}
Competitor::~Competitor(){
    //does nothing for now
}
void Competitor::setTime(float t){
    time = t;
}

//ranker.h

#ifndef __Olym__ranker__
#define __Olym__ranker__
#include <vector>
#include "competitor.h"
using namespace std;
int passed = 0;
class Ranker {
    bool boolean = true;
public:
    vector<Competitor*> rv;
    Ranker(int lanes);
    ~Ranker();
    int addList(Competitor* c);
    Competitor* getLane(int lane);
    Competitor* getFinish(int finish);
    int getFilled();
};
#endif

//ranker.cpp

#include "ranker.h"
Ranker::Ranker(int lan){
    rv.resize(lan - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i <= rv.size(); i++){
        rv[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
Ranker::~Ranker(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= rv.size(); i++){
        delete rv[i];
    }
}
int Ranker::addList(Competitor *c){
    if(c != NULL && passed <= 4){
        rv[passed++] = c;
        return passed - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
 Competitor* Ranker::getLane(int lane){
    for(int i = 0; i <= rv.size(); i++){
        if(rv[i]->getLane() == lane && rv[i] != NULL){
            return rv[i];
        }
    }
    return rv[0];
}
Competitor* Ranker::getFinish(int finish){
    if(boolean){
        Competitor *temp = nullptr;
        int highestIndex;
        for(int i = rv.size(); i >= 0; i--){
            highestIndex = i;
            for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--){
                if(rv[j] != nullptr && rv[highestIndex] != nullptr){
                    if(rv[j]->getTime() > rv[highestIndex]->getTime())
                        highestIndex = j;
                }
            }
            temp = rv[i];
            rv[i] = rv[highestIndex];
            rv[highestIndex] = temp;   
        }
        delete temp;
        temp = *new Competitor*;
        boolean = false;
    }
    return rv[finish - 1];
}
int Ranker::getFilled(){
    int filled = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= rv.size(); i++){
        if(rv[i] != NULL){
            filled++;
        }
    }
     return filled;
}

//olympic.h

#ifndef _Olympic_Lab__olympic__
#define _Olympic_Lab__olympic__
#include "ranker.h"
#endif

//olympic.cpp

#include "olympic.h"

 int main(){
    const int lanes = 4;
    Ranker rank(lanes);
    Competitor* starters[4];
    starters[0] = new Competitor("EmmyLou Harris", 1);
    starters[1] = new Competitor("Nanci Griffith", 2);
    starters[2] = new Competitor("Bonnie Raitt", 3);
    starters[3] = new Competitor("Joni Mitchell", 4); 
    starters[0]->setTime((float)12.0);
    starters[1]->setTime((float)12.8);
    starters[2]->setTime((float)11.0);
    starters[3]->setTime((float)10.3);
    for(int i = 0; i < lanes; i++){
        rank.addList(starters[i]);
    }
    cout << "Competitors by lane are:" << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= lanes; i++)
        rank.getLane(i)->print();
    cout << "Rankings by finish are:" << endl;
    for(int i = 1; i <= lanes; i++)
        rank.getFinish(i)->print();
    for(int i = 0; i < lanes; i++){
        delete starters[i];
    }
}
```

It would be appreciated if someone could assist me in finding **exactly** what causes this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable in a header it will be duplicated in every file that includes the header.

So `int passed = 0;` in ranker.h is going to give you a lot of grief. ranker and olympian both have allocated a different `passed` and the linker now has no clue which one is the real passed.

So what you probably want is

```
extern int passed;
```

in ranker.h to declare that passed will exist at some point, if it doesn't yet, so it doesn't need to be allocated. The compiler will happily carry on and allow you to use `passed`.

And then in ranker.cpp, declare

```
int passed = 0;
```

to allocate `passed` and satisfy the linker. Now you have only one `passed` and anyone who includes ranker.h can see and use it.

If you want more than one `passed`, you have to do something else so that they don't share the same name and scope, but this doesn't look like your goal.

Off topic: resist the urge to put `using namespace std;`in a header file. It can lead to future problems that can be very hard to debug. More here: [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)